# Change URL inside of <a> Depending on If User Selects "Yes" or "No"

Tags: javascript

I have a short questionnaire and I want to send people that are 18 and over to 1 link, and people that are younger than 18 to another.

The first question (the only one that filters) is "Are you older than 18?" and depending if the user clicks yes or no, I want that to change the URL inside of `href="..."`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```html
<div id="Q1">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">Question 1 of 3<span class="pull-right">
                  <script>document.write(lmonth + " " + date + ", " + year);</script></span></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <h4>Are you older than 18?</h4>
       <div class="radio Q1">
        <label> <input type="radio">Yes.</label>
       </div>
       <div class="radio Q1">
        <label> <input type="radio">No.</label>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="wall">
       <h3>You Qualify!</h3>
       <a href="http://url-if-older-tha-18.com">Continue</a>
    </div>
```

I would like to do this with pure javascript and no jquery if possible

Comment: Hi Joe, what JavaScript have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not simply use both Yes and No buttons as links instead? But I guess you could use [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) to the `click` event and then [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the `<a href>` element and change it's contents.

Comment: For your radio buttons, add a name="over-18" attribute, as at the moment they are both selectable simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the URL of an anchor tag by changing its href property:

```
<a id="link" href="http://google.com">link</a>

document.getElementById("link").href = "http://bing.com";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gbsm0mhn/

Comment: how does this change depending on if the user clicks yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<input type="radio" name="yes" value="yes" id="yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="no" value="no" id="no"> No<br>

<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link">This is link</a>
```

JS

```
let yesRadio = document.getElementById('yes');
let link = document.getElementById('link');

if(yesRadio.checked = true) {
  link.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
} else {
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `eventListener` trigger on `change` event, then find the checked radio with `:checked` pseudo-class. I commented out the first script block since it's not part of the question and assuming that you have that part functioning correctly.

Details are commented in Snippet

#### SNIPPET

```html
<div id="Q1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Question 1 of 3<span class="pull-right">
                  <!--<script>document.write(lmonth + " " + date + ", " + year);</script>--></span></h3>
    </div>
    
    <!--Changed div to form added id=Q1-->
    <!--
    Added name='rad' to each radio button, 
    this allows us to hook into both values.
    Added value='yes' and 'no'
    -->
    <form id='Q1' class="panel-body">
      <h4>Are you older than 18?</h4>
      <div class="radio Q1">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name='rad' value='yes'>Yes.</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio Q1">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name='rad' value='no'>No.</label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="wall">
  <h3>You Qualify!</h3>
  <a href="http://url-if-older-tha-18.com">Continue</a>
</div>
<script>
  // Reference the form
  var form = document.getElementById('Q1');
  
  // Register a change event on form which will trigger event handler: radioAnswer()
  form.addEventListener('change', radioAnswer, false);

  function radioAnswer() {
    // Reference anchor
    var link = document.querySelector('#wall > a');
    // Reference the VALUE of the checked radio button
    var rad = form.querySelector("input[name=rad]:checked").value;
    // If VALUE is 'yes' change anchor href to example.com otherwise domain.com
    if (rad === 'yes') {
      link.href = 'http://example.com';
    } else {
      link.href = 'http://domain.com';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: out of all the answers this 1 seems to be working the way im trying to do this, but is there a way to get this to work based on an ID or Class instead of this line: `var rad = form.querySelector("input[name=rad]:checked").value;`? thanks!

Comment: Add a class to each radio, like `.rad`, then `var rad = form.querySelector(".rad:checked").value;`. That looks much cleaner. If this answer resolved your issue, please click the green ***✔***

Comment: is there a way to do this based on if i give `yes` a class of `y1` and `no` a class of `n1`? I'm trying to do it just based on the class or id name if they are unique so if `y1` is clicked the anchor will be `domain1.com` and if `n1` is clicked the anchor will be `domain2.com`.  is htis possible? im just trying to remove any relation to a form from the code since there will not always be a form

Comment: Using classes is a better solution, that's great that you deduced that yourself. I didn't add classes in my example because OPs usually comprehend faster if you keep things as close as possible to the original code. Definitely do that. Ids make writing the script easier as long as you know for certain that that's the only one on the page.