# Enable a button when one of radio buttons is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link that looks like a button because of CSS. My CSS class is:

```
.classButton {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #818181 0%, #656565 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The link is:

```
<p class="classButton"><a href="https://www.elso.org/Excellence/AOE/StartMyApplication.aspx" style="color:#ffffff;">Start application</a></p>
```

I also have JavaScript function:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".classButton").click(function(){ 
          window.location = "https://www.elso.org/Excellence/AOE/StartMyApplication.aspx" 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

I should add two radio buttons 1. Path to Excellent 2. Award of Excellence. At start the button "Start application" should be disabled.I have to enable this button when one of the radio buttons is checked, and post in GET AwardType=? 1 or 2, depends on that if the first or the second radio button is checked. How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: I think I just answered the same question from a classmate of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40642405/2813224 if this helps, upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var url = 'https://www.elso.org/Excellence/AOE/StartMyApplication.aspx?‌​AwardType=';

    $(".classButton").removeClass('disabled');

    url += $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    console.log(url);

    $(".classButton a").prop('href', url);
  });

  $(".classButton").click(function(e) { 
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }); 
});
```

```css
.classButton {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #818181 0%, #656565 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.classButton a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.classButton.disabled {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="classButton disabled">
  <a href="">Start</a>
</p>

<p>
  <label for="input_1">Value 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="input_1" name="radio" value="1" />
</p>

<p>
  <label for="input_2">Value 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="input_2" name="radio" value="2" />
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @ZoltanToth for your help and attention. I just put the real url to the code and have `https://www.elso.org/Excellence/AOE/StartMyApplication.aspx?AwardType=AddNewModule` instead of AwardType=1 or 2. I cannot find why.Have you got any idea? :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: I updated the answer with your real URL. As you can see it works just fine, so the issue you have is caused by something beside the code you posted here..

Comment: Just one small question :) The button click has effect only when the user clicks on the text. Is it possible to have effect when the user clicks anywhere on the button? Thank you in advance.

Comment: updated the code :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Instead of using `<p class="classButton">` on either side of the a href link, use `<span class="classButton">` that way `<p>` css doesn't effect the button.

2) For the button: `<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="check_function()">`

3) For the radio buttons:

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" value="Path to Excellent">
<input id="radio2" type="radio" value="Award of Excellence">
```

3) Javascript:

```
function check_function(){

if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked == false) {

        window.location.replace = "https://www.elso.org/Excellence/AOE/StartMyApplication.aspx"
};

else {

        window.location.replace = "https://www.elso.org/Excellence/AOE/StartMyApplication2.aspx"
}; 

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is useful.